# Great sample application in PHP demonstrating the most recent best practices in CRUD

Tags: php, templates, crud, sample

Do you know some tutorials (website, blog or video) in PHP demonstrating the most recent best practices in CRUD?

What I'm looking for is similar to the Pet Store for Java EE and PetShop in C# released a few years ago.

I am also aware of WishList, the Netbeans e-Commerce Tutorial for PHP, but I'm looking for an updated sample code that implements today's best practices in PHP development without using a framework.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Using a modern framework like symfony, laravel, codeigniter, cakePHP, you could learn many modern practices in PHP and security. They are, in a way, sample modern practices. However opinionated

Comment: I'm looking for examples using no framework.  Thank you!

Comment: In the end, when you create your app, it becomes a mini-framework of sorts. If all is done properly

Comment: [Try this list](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=DPeYWuWTEoyItQWQp42ICg&q=best+modern+practices+in+PHP&oq=best+modern+practices+in+PHP&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30k1l10.648.4204.0.4605.29.14.0.2.2.0.444.1788.1j1j1j2j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..21.8.1797.0..0j0i20i264k1j0i22i30k1j0i8i13i30k1.0.2Jn2sAvNdfQ) and [this is also good](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info)